# redirect is throwing a "Resource was found at " exception in turbogears 2.3

Tags: python-2.7, redirect, turbogears2

When a user is accessing a certain controller and if a condition is met, then i want to redirect user to some other page but when I'am trying that it throwing "Resource was found at exception". Below is the code which I'm trying.

```
@expose("sample.templates.show_id")
def show_id(self, **kw):
    try:
        if kw['u']==1:
            redirect ("/")
        else:
            groups = self.handle_u(kw['u'])
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
    return dict(groups=groups)
```

When the kw['u']==1, then it is not taking me to the index page, but throwing the mentioned error. Please suggest me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirect` throws an `HTTPFound` exception, so you are catching it in the `except` clause. Probably you want to make the `except` more specific or move the `redirect`  out of the `try`.

Comment: thank you very much. Just wanted to know how can I import HTTPFound exception so that when this exception occurs, I can easily raise it. Currently I am using sys.exc_info()[0].__name__ to find the name of exception and then raising it.

Comment: `from tg.exceptions import HTTPFound`